# Initialize several charts in a loop

Tags: javascript, chart.js

On my page, I want to show multiple charts that are loaded via ajax. So I get html that is something like this:

```
<h4>Chart 1</h4>
<canvas data-type="bar" data-labels='["Label 1", "Label 2"]' data-data='[10,20]'></canvas>
<h4>Chart 2</h4>
<canvas data-type="pie" data-labels='["Label 3", "Label 4"]' data-data='[30,40]'></canvas>
```

As you can see, the charts can be of different types and I have an object holding all the configuration of charts for each type

```
const chartConfigs = {
    bar: {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: [],
          datasets: [{
            data: [],
            pointRadius: 2,
            backgroundColor: '',
            maxBarThickness: 50
          }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: barScalesOptions
        }
    },
    pie: {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: ['#84c267', '#c9556a'],
                borderWidth: 0
            }],
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
          labels: {
            fontColor: '#CCC',
          }
        },
            aspectRatio: 1,
            responsive: true
        }
    }
}
```

And I loop through all the canvases to initialize them.

```
container.querySelectorAll('canvas').forEach(canv => {
    const chartOptions = chartConfigs[canv.dataset.type];
    chartOptions.data.datasets[0].data = JSON.parse(canv.dataset.data);
    if(canv.dataset.labels != undefined)
        chartOptions.data.labels = JSON.parse(canv.dataset.labels);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(chartOptions));
    new Chart(canv, chartOptions);
});
```

But the problem is that all the charts are rendered the same - Labels and Data. I'm assuming its because `chartOptions` is a copy by reference. Its a pretty difficult task to do a deep copy  as this is a nested object and I also need functions in them. But even if I somehow did this task, it would be a memory management nightmare as there are many charts on the page.

If you have done something like this before, please share a better way of doing this.

Comment: have you omitted the functions in the `chartOptions` or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah I didn't include it here but there are functions in some cases

Comment: are they many functions? how when do you call them, on events or ...?

Comment: p.s.: I updated my answer maybe this helps

Comment: The functions are like dynamically determining the color of bars or formating the numbers, they are called by Chartjs. I think I'll go with your `Json.parse()` option. I'm creating the function like this `if(chartOptions.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor == 'numberColors') chartOptions.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = numberColors;`. So replacing the string with the actual function.

Answer (score 0):

A *quick solution* is to clone the needed part of the object, with the handy function(s) `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, it makes sure it breaks all references (as [mentioned on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy)).

```
container.querySelectorAll('canvas').forEach(canv => {
    const chartOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chartConfigs[canv.dataset.type]));
    chartOptions.data.datasets[0].data = JSON.parse(canv.dataset.data);
    if(canv.dataset.labels != undefined){
        chartOptions.data.labels = JSON.parse(canv.dataset.labels);


    console.log(JSON.stringify(chartOptions));
    new Chart(canv, chartOptions);
});
```

> Since I can't see any functions in the object `chartOptions` the serializing and deserializing should be no problem?

**Update, for object with functions *(for your specific case)*:**

I see two easy options,

1. just extract the functions from the base object and just pass the current object
2. Or **if you don't want to alter** the `chartConfigs` object, just use the `prototype` function, `call` ([link to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)). With other words change the function calls to:

   ```
   // clone
   const chartOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chartConfigs[canv.dataset.type]));
   ...
   let id = 1;
   let value = 100;

   // call the function
   chartConfigs[chartOptions.typ].testFunction.call(chartOptions, id, value);
   ...
   ```

> *(if `testFunction` would be a function, with 2 parameters ( `id`, `value`))*

Is not very sexy, but is a fast solution, that will need little code modifications.